# How to select all Dataframe columns with the same names?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am creating a dataframe based on a csv import:

```
ID, attachment, attachment, comment, comment
1, lol.jpg, lmfao.png, 'Luigi',
2, cat.docx, , 'It's me', 'Mario'
```

Basically the number of 'attachments' and 'comment' columns corresponds to the line that has the bigger number of said attachment and comment.
Since I am exporting the CSV from a third party software, I do not know in advance how many attachments and comment columns there will be.

Importing this CSV with `pd.read_csv` creates the following dataframe

|  | ID | attachment | attachment.1 | comment | comment.1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | lol.jpg | lmfao.png | 'Luigi' |  |
| 1 | 2 | cat.docx |  | 'It's me' | 'Mario' |

Is there a simple way to select all attachment/comment columns?

Such as `attachments_df = imported_df.attachment.all` or `comments_df = imported_df['comment].??`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.filter`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) for columns starting by `string` by `^` and optionaly `.` with `\d` for comma with decimal for end of string is used `$`:

```
attachments_df = imported_df.filter(regex='^attachment\.*\d*$')
comments_df = imported_df.filter(regex='^comment\.*\d*$')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```
attachments_df = imported_df.loc[:,imported_df.columns.str.startswith('attachment')]
comments_df = imported_df.loc[:,imported_df.columns.str.startswith('comment')]
```

Answer (score 1):

you also can use `like` atribute of `filter` function:

```
imported_df.filter(like='attach')
'''
  attachment attachment.1
0    lol.jpg    lmfao.png
1   cat.docx          NaN
```